# Azure function import pyodbc error after publishing

Tags: azure, azure-functions

First- thanks a ton for all your posts and responses that helped me immensely getting this far!

I have successfully created an Azure function that has import pyodbc, azure.function like shown below.

```
*import logging
import pyodbc
import json
import azure.functions as func
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) ->  func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    try:*
```

It works fine in VS Code but when I try to run it after publishing, it fails with

```
**2019-11-22T14:31:17.743 [Information] Executing 'Functions.godataexcelautomation' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=79cebf6c-b371-4a12-b623-16931abe7757)
2019-11-22T14:31:17.761 [Error] Executed 'Functions.godataexcelautomation' (Failed, Id=79cebf6c-b371-4a12-b623-16931abe7757)
Result: Failure
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
Stack:   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 242, in _handle__function_load_request
    func_request.metadata.entry_point)
  File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.6/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 66, in load_function
    mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/godataexcelautomation/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyodbc**
```

Appreciate any help you can.. seems like I need make pyodbc available to azure portal? in the .json file?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have `pyobdc` in your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Hi @ASUB6, has your issue been solved ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as you when I deploy python function from VS code directly.Pls have a check that you have added `pyobdc` in your `requirements.txt` and try the command below to deploy your python function , it solved my issue:

```
func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME> --build remote
```

Btw,you should define `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` as odbc driver on python function.

Result : 
[image]